# R.java not getting generated and AIDL files not getting compiled in Android SDK 2.3

Tags: android, sdk

i noticed that ADB.exe moved to platform-tools on Android 2.3 SDK and added it to the path so thats fine. But now, even with all tools and Eclipse plugin updated, my R.java does not get generated and the AIDL files get not converted into stub classes -> ergo the whole gen folder is empty (even if i delete the whole folder or clean my project). Our build is broken due to this and i want to ask if someone had/has the same experience and maybe some solution to this problem?

thanks
Robert

Comment: Evidently the resource compiler is failing. What does Eclipse's Console and Problems windows show? Btw, you only needed to update your PATH for using adb.exe etc outside of Eclipse... the updated ADT will always know where to find adb.exe (relative to what you set the Android SDK root to in Preferences of course).

Comment: hi yes i think that too and i wonder why it fails. in the problems i just see compile errors (resolve errors because AIDL files do not get compiled, and resources are not found). in the console no message is displayed.

Comment: I have problems running the AVDs in 2.3 but I can at least build apps with .aidl files in them. I noticed that when I installed 2.3, Norton Security quarantined aidl.exe. I had to restore it. Do you have an aidl.exe in the new platform-tools folder?

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. After upgrading to SDK tools r10 and SDK platform-tools r3, it worked fine for a couple days, until I changed a layout and a value in attrs.xml. Reverting the changes doesn't help. The AIDL stubs are not getting built anymore.

Comment: Anyone got an actual fix for this? I am having the same problem and none of the fixes work

Comment: After doing a fresh install of Helios, as I mention below, the problem's apparently gone for good. Did you try that?

Answer (score 0):

There is an entry with some hints about how you should upgrade to 2.3 with Eclipse:

http://ggomeze.com/2010/12/09/updating-eclipse-to-gingerbread

Probably your resources didn't get build because of the new "formatted" feature coming with 2.3. Review your string.xml files, and make sure you use the proper syntax.

Comment: Doesn't work, is there more than just strings that need to be changed?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by doing a *fresh install* of Eclipse Helios (I was using Ganymede before that). I then reimported my projects, and the problem's gone.